# How do I run .ui files in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, python, qt-creator

I created a very basic .ui file and edited it using pyqt. Now when I click the ui file, it opens in QT Designer. How do I run it? All it does in print ham (hehe). I'm sorry about my language, Please edit this question if needed.

Comment: When you say you created a very basic UI file, did you create it using qtDesigner? Usually if you are working with PyQt, you don't bother (at least two years ago when I did this sort of thing) with the .UI file.

Comment: yes, I am useing QT Designer and PyQt. I dont get it. How do I run it?

Comment: No; DID YOU >>>>CREATE<<<< THE UI FILE USING QTDESIGNER. Come into IRC at #ubuntu-app-devel, and we can probably help you better there.

Comment: Yes. I CREATED IT using QTDESIGNER.

Comment: Ah okay. Then in order to run a .ui file, you need to open it using qtdesigner. The .ui files don't function on their own, so they are not runnable as an executable.

Comment: I have used the command `pyuic4 <Inputfile.ui> > <outfile_ui_.py>` to edit it and now I want to run it. I want the widget I created. How do i do that? Can ubuntu do that?